# Existing class not in dir

Tags: python, inheritance, sympy, symbolic-math

I meant to understand (parts of) the inheritance tree of `sympy`.
For that, I did

```
1 b = sym.Symbol('b')
2 print(type(b))
3 print(dir(sympy.core))
4 print(dir(sympy.core.symbol))

<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
['BasicMeta', 'Registry', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'all_classes', 'division', 'ordering_of_classes', 'print_function']
...
AttributeError: module 'sympy.core.core' has no attribute 'symbol'
```

From the result of line 2, I expected `symbol` to be in the list printed out in line 3.
And then I expected `Symbol` to be in the list printed out in line 4.

But the first did not happen, raising an error. And line 4 did not even execute.

**Why is that?**
**How can I deal fail-proof with cases like this?**
**What should I do to inspect the inheritance tree about `Symbol`?**

Comment: `module 'sympy.core.core'` > take a look at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/core.py

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusing mix of import styles across the sympy codebase. Actually this has already been changed since the last release so running your example on sympy master gives:

```
<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
['Add', 'AlgebraicNumber', 'Atom', 'AtomicExpr', 'Basic', 'Catalan', 'Derivative', 'Dict', 'Dummy', 'E', 'Eq', 'Equality', 'EulerGamma', 'Expr', 'Float', 'Function', 'FunctionClass', 'Ge', 'GoldenRatio', 'GreaterThan', 'Gt', 'I', 'Integer', 'Lambda', 'Le', 'LessThan', 'Lt', 'Mod', 'Mul', 'N', 'Ne', 'Number', 'NumberSymbol', 'PoleError', 'Pow', 'PrecisionExhausted', 'Rational', 'RealNumber', 'Rel', 'S', 'StrictGreaterThan', 'StrictLessThan', 'Subs', 'Symbol', 'SympifyError', 'TribonacciConstant', 'Tuple', 'Unequality', 'UnevaluatedExpr', 'Wild', 'WildFunction', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'add', 'alphabets', 'arity', 'assumptions', 'basic', 'cache', 'cacheit', 'comp', 'compatibility', 'containers', 'core', 'coreerrors', 'count_ops', 'decorators', 'diff', 'evalf', 'evaluate', 'expand', 'expand_complex', 'expand_func', 'expand_log', 'expand_mul', 'expand_multinomial', 'expand_power_base', 'expand_power_exp', 'expand_trig', 'expr', 'exprtools', 'factor_nc', 'factor_terms', 'facts', 'function', 'gcd_terms', 'igcd', 'ilcm', 'integer_log', 'integer_nthroot', 'logic', 'mod', 'mod_inverse', 'mul', 'multidimensional', 'nan', 'nfloat', 'numbers', 'oo', 'operations', 'parameters', 'pi', 'power', 'preorder_traversal', 'prod', 'relational', 'rules', 'seterr', 'singleton', 'symbol', 'symbols', 'sympify', 'var', 'vectorize', 'zoo']
['AtomicExpr', 'Basic', 'Boolean', 'Dummy', 'Expr', 'FunctionClass', 'S', 'StdFactKB', 'Symbol', 'Tuple', 'Wild', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_assume_defined', '_filter_assumptions', '_range', '_re', '_symbol', '_uniquely_named_symbol', 'cacheit', 'cartes', 'disambiguate', 'division', 'fuzzy_bool', 'is_sequence', 'ordered', 'print_function', 'random', 'sift', 'string', 'symbols', 'sympify', 'var']
```

The reason for the confusion is that (in sympy 1.5.1):

1. `sympy/__init__.py` does `from sympy.core import *`
2. `sympy/core/__init__.py` does not define `__all__`
3. The core package has a submodule called `core` (`sympy.core.core`).

So when you do `sympy.core` in 1.5.1 you actually get the `sympy.core.core` module from `sympy/core/core.py` whereas on master it correctly gives the `sympy.core` package.

A more direct way to get the module is

````py
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> b = sym.Symbol('b')
>>> b.__module__
'sympy.core.symbol'
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules[b.__module__]
<module 'sympy.core.symbol' from 'sympy/core/symbol.py'>```
````

I would just open up `sympy/core/symbol.py` if I wanted to see what was in there.

For exploring inheritance trees you might find `mro` useful:

```
>>> type(b).mro()
[<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>, <class 'sympy.core.expr.AtomicExpr'>, <class 'sympy.core.basic.Atom'>, <class 'sympy.core.expr.Expr'>, <class 'sympy.logic.boolalg.Boolean'>, <class 'sympy.core.basic.Basic'>, <class 'sympy.core.evalf.EvalfMixin'>, <class 'object'>]
```